# AngularJS Unit Test: Mocked promise is resolved but method still returns a promise?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I am testing 'ServiceOne' which uses a method called "get" inside of a second service, 'ServiceTwo'.  The get() method inside of 'ServiceTwo' makes an `$http` call, so it returns a promise until the `$http` call is resolved.  The 'ServiceOne' method that I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
serviceOne.getNewId = function (oldId) {
    var url = "http://mock.com";

    return serviceTwo.get(url).then(function (returned) {
        if (returned.data !== undefined) {
            return returned.data[0].newId;
        } else {
            return oldId;
        }
    });
};
```

Here is my test for `getNewId()` in ServiceOne:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_serviceOne_,_$q_, _$rootScope_, _serviceTwo_) {

    serviceOne = _serviceOne_;
    serviceTwo = _serviceTwo_;

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
}));

it('should return a newId', inject(function (serviceTwo) {        
    spyOn(serviceTwo, 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    var returnedData = {data:[{newId: '95'}]};
    deferred.resolve(returnedData);

    var retVal = serviceOne.getNewId('322');       
    $rootScope.$apply();

    expect(retVal).toBe('95');  //fails
}));
```

`retVal` is being returned as a promise object, instead of the expected string '95'.  So, I can get my test to pass if I go into the promise object and look for the value:

```
expect(retVal.$$state.value).toBe('95');  //passes
```

The returned promise object has a status of 1, so I know that it has been resolved.  And the promise's value is correct, set to '95' as if the logic within the function of my then() has been executed.  Why am I getting this error message when I run Karma?

```
Expected Promise({ $$state: Object({ status: 1, value: '95' }) }) to be '95'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with promises they don't return the value, they return a promise so you have to restructure your test like this:

```
it('should return a newId', inject(function (serviceTwo) {        
    spyOn(serviceTwo, 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    var returnedData = {data:[{newId: '95'}]};
    var retVal;

    serviceOne.getNewId('322')
        .then(function(result){
            retVal = result;
        });

    deferred.resolve(returnedData);

    $rootScope.$apply();

    expect(retVal).toBe('95');  //should pass
}));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!